# Scatter-Gather implementation

Tags: events, soa, esb, complex-event-processing

I am a programmer working in the domain of information system integration (SOA, ESB, messages broker etc...).

At the moment I am working on a proprietary ESB which unfortunately does not implement the [Scatter-Gather pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/BroadcastAggregate.html).

Actually, I would be interested in a solution to implement this pattern asynchronously. Meaning in [this example](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/img/BroadcastAggregate.gif), the *Best Quote* is not managed in the same synchronous transaction than *Quote Request* (e.g. not a synchronous request/reply service).

Because we are talking about asynchronous processing, I am looking for a reliable solution. As an example, if the Vendor B fails (due to a technical issue), I do not want to send back a error *Quote Request*. I have to consider the whole transaction as a guaranteed one and being able to reprocess the call to Vendor B at one point in time. Then the transaction would magically continue and I would be able to send back a successful *Quote Request*.

I have already been able to implement this pattern in the past using a proprietary Complex Event Processing (CEP) tool. Indeed the CEP tool was able to persist the global transaction state and to correlate events coming back from Vendor A, B and C.

So I was wondering if there was an existing *lightweight* solution to implement this pattern in a reliable way.

Last but not least I do not search another ESB tool. I know that Apache Camel, Spring Integration, Mule or WSO2 are implementing this pattern but I was rather interested in a dedicated solution.

Thanks

Comment: "but I was rather interested in a dedicated solution" - what does that mean?

Comment: A comment from Udi Dahan himself? What a great moment :)
I wanted to say that I do not look for another ESB (I have already one), I wanted a dedicated solution to manage event correlation, event filtering etc... So far my best match is Apache Storm but the scatter-gather implementation is not really out of the box.

Comment: Storm is not really a lightweight solution. But you could use Camel as a library, i.e. in-process.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements fall in two broad spaces. Event correlation/filtering is usually done with a CEP engine while the integration patterns like Scatter-Gather are to be done with an ESB. It's true that a CEP engine will facilitate some level of message transformation and integration capabilities while an ESB will also support basic filtering/correlations of events (mostly event processing rather than complex event processing), but these are not the purposes they are originally designed for.

So if it can't be implemented using one of ESB or CEP servers, your solution can include both CEP and ESB servers, each performing some specific set of tasks they are best suited for. (it's unlikely that a vendor building a combined server to perform all these stuff)

Having said that, if you are going to implement this with WSO2 products, and if you really need a single server instance, you can consider installing CEP features on top of the ESB as explained [in this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Feature+Management). Otherwise, you can connect the two servers using a high-performant protocol like Thrift.

Comment: Actually I have only one requirement which is to implement the scatter-gather pattern. I understand your point even if I do not fully agree with you because all ESBs don't implement it. Sure all "moderns" ESB based on EIP patterns (because the scatter-gather is an EIP) take it into account but that's not the case with "classic" ones such as TIBCO or webMethods. Thanks for your comment though.